# How to stop an activity from a non-activity-class?

Tags: java, android

I've got a problem: I've got an app with a Navigation-Drawer. So I've got the DetailFragment.java class:

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
public class DetailFragment extends Fragment {

FrameLayout fLayout;

View view;
Context videoContext;
Context context;

public DetailFragment() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container, Bundle args) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_detail_fragment, container, false);
    String menu = getArguments().getString("Menu");

    switch (menu) {
        case ("Home"): {
            fLayout = (FrameLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.home) ;
            fLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            break;
        }

        case ("Info"): {
            fLayout = (FrameLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.info) ;
            fLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            break;
        }

        case ("Video"): {
            startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), VideoActivity.class));
            break;
        }
    }

    return view;
    }
}
```

You see, in the 3rd case 'Video', I start an Activity witch play a video. But when I click on another Button in the Switch-Structure, the Activity runs in background and the video too. How can I stop the activity in the other Case-Statements so the Video is not running in background any more?

Thank you for any help, 
Konstantin.

PS: Sorry for my bad English, I'm only 12 and from Germany :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I stop an Activity from a non-Activity class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28197045/how-do-i-stop-an-activity-from-a-non-activity-class)

Answer (score 0):

```
if(getActivity().class.getSimpleName=="VideoActivity")   
 ((Activity)getActivity()).finish();
```

This line in each of the cases should do it.